# Why checking if double is NaN doesn't work in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a working way to check if a double variable is NaN?

I tried:

```dart
variable.isNaN
variable == double.nan
```

Here the complete code:

```dart
bool isValidQuantity(String s) {
  double converted = toDouble(s);
  if (converted == double.nan || converted < 0) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

`toDouble()` is a function of the library validators version 2.0.0+1

It just returns `double.nan` in this case so I don't get why false isn't returned by the `isValidQuantity()` function

Comment: yes, `variable.isNaN` - why do you think it is not working?

Comment: @pskink I added some details

Comment: you have `converted == double.nan`, not `converted.isNaN`

Comment: @pskink tried both!!!

Comment: no, `isNaN` is working just fine: `var nan = double.nan;
  print(nan);
  print(nan.isNaN);`

Comment: Ok, you are right.. maybe debugging I didn't reloaded the right way. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine. However, you might want to initialize your variable because in dart everything is Object(any int, float, bool etc) and default values of the object are **Null**.

```
  var myVar = 0.0;
    if (myVar.isNaN)
      print('Not a number');
    else
      print('${myVar} is a number');
```

Comment: Yeah, i know, in fact I've initializated it before my if statement